# cmake add_library doesn't initialize static global variable

Tags: c++, cmake

I have two source files, main.cc, foo.cc.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "main\n";
}
```

foo.cc

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class foo {
public:
    foo() {
        cout << "foo ctor\n";
    }
};

static foo foo_obj;
```

When I manually compile like this:

> $ g++ -c foo.cc -o libfoo.a
>
> $ g++ main.cc libfoo.a -o main
>
> $ ./main
>
> foo ctor
>
> main

But when I use cmake, it won't print `foo ctor`. Here's the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

add_library(foo STATIC foo.cc)

add_executable(main main.cc)
target_link_libraries(main foo)
```

Obviously cmake has done something that I don't expect.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ It's not the same question, I think. I'm not asking the initialization order across TU. My question is related to some cmake issue, comparing my manual operation's result.

Comment: It doesn't matter that its not the same question but you'll find the answer there. There's no guarantee that `std::cout` will be initialized before `foo_obj`. Nothing to do with CMake BTW.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - `cout` is initialized by a schwartz counter. It's not subject to the SIOF.

Comment: @Lewis - You are gonna have to examine the makefiles that Cmake generated. No other way to debug it.

Comment: It turns out that cmake generate libfoo.a by `ar qc libfoo.a foo.cc`, which results in above situation. @StoryTeller @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks.

Comment: @LewisChan I decided to reopen. Feel free to describe the situation and answer your question.

Comment: `foo.cc` is not linked here, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628469/is-lto-allowed-to-remove-unused-global-object-if-there-is-code-in-a-different-tr/56628645#56628645

Comment: Command line `g++ -c foo.cc -o libfoo.a` doesn't create a *static library*. Resulted file is just an **object** one, so its better to name it as `foo.o`. But with command `add_library` CMake actually creates a **static library** using `ar` command. (With full command `ar qc libfoo.a foo.o`, not with `foo.cc` as you note in the comment).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Oooh, you're right. I didn't realize that...

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that `-Wl,--whole-archive` can be used to avoid this. For example write this:

```
target_link_libraries(main 
  "-Wl,--whole-archive"
  foo
  "-Wl,--no-whole-archive"
)
```